# Robot Framework how to get JSON value by using second value

Tags: json, robotframework

How can I get a certain value out of JSON if I know one specific value.
If I want to extract car type and I know the car name.
I have try different variations of this:
`${GetType}=  Get Value From Json  ${CarList.json()}  $..type[?($.name=Focus)]`

```
[
  {
    "Manuafacture": "BMW",
    "Engine": [
      {
        "volume": 3,
        "filter": 222,
        "name": "Turbo-dd"
      }
    ],
    "name": "320",
    "type": "333-44-12"
  },
  {
    "Manuafacture": "Ford",
    "Engine": [
      {
        "volume": 2,
        "filters": 1111,
        "name": "doch"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Focus",
    "type": "444-55-33"
  },
  {
    "Manuafacture": "Audi",
    "Engine": [
      {
        "volume": 3,
        "filters": 444,
        "name": "TFSI"
      }
    ],
    "name": "A6",
    "type": "999-88-77"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your filter expression you are not referencing to the current element (`@`), but root element (`$`). Also equals sign should be used twice (`==`). So something like that should work:

`$[?(@.name=="Focus")].type`